# Adiabatic Quantum Computing vs Adiabatic Quantum Optimization vs Quantum Annealing

Tags: annealing, adiabatic-model

I am aware that of the difference of Adiabatic Quantum Computing (AQC) and Quantum Annealing (QA) as explained [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17703/quantum-annealing-vs-adiabatic-quantum-computation). However, another term which came up in some papers was **Adiabatic Quantum Optimization (AQO)**. Where does AQO fit in among AQC and QA?

It seems that it is another name for QA and is restricted to solving the Ising model, just like D-Wave's QA? I would think AQO is more general than QA where QA is a form of AQO where its Hamiltonian can be any algebraic function of spin variables without restrictions on the interaction, unlike the Ising model.

Anyone mind clarifying this? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm very happy my answer from 3 years ago to that question is still helping people!

The answer to your new question is found here:

[image]

Notice that there is ***another*** term here which is "Quantum Adiabatic Algorithm" or QAA. In fact those QAA papers from 2000 and 2001 papers call it "Quantum Adiabatic Evolution Algorithm" or QAEA, and "Quantum Computation by Adiabatic Evolution" or QCAE.

---

I think we should agree on just using the terms AQC and Quantum Annealing to describe the two things in my answer to the question you provided the link to.

Comment: Keep in mind, these terms have only started to pop up in the literature relatively recently, compared to words like "electron" and "qubit" which have more mature "textbook" definitions. People have not yet agreed on a "single" best way of describe these things.